# Получение новых данных из БД

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongo

Подскажите как правильно реализовать получение новых данных (Если они есть) из БД и отображение их на клиенте.
(Это компонент, отображающий последние действия пользователей)

**Клиент** React

**Бэкэнд** Node.js

**БД** Mongo.DB

Сейчас у меня для этого существует отдельный метод, к которому я обращаюсь с клиента каждые 10 секунд, получая данные из нужной мне коллекци. Понимаю что нагружать сервер таким количеством запросов неправильно.

Рассматриваю использования Вебсокетов, верное ли это решение в моей ситуации?
Возможно стоит сменить БД?

Заранее благодарен за советы.

Comment: через WebSocket уведомлять?.. как в онлайн-чатах и пр.

Comment: Не совсем, это блок, в котором списком выводятся последние действия пользователей. Собственно нужно обновлять эти данные на актуальные

Comment: Тут вопрос скорее в том, как правильно мониторить наличие новых данных в БД.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: с реляционными данными и ORM обычно имеются события жизненного цикла объекта. Что на ноде с монгой - не знаю...но вполне возможно что какая-то из реализаций тоже может генерить какие-то события, на которые можно подписаться. В противном случае можно это реализовать самому

Comment: Сокет поможет снять нагрузку. Сервер будет 1 раз делать запрос в БД, результат бродкастом рассылать всем подключенным пользователям. Можно еще и хранилище данных прикрутить и туда сохранять результат вызова БД, что бы новые пользователи не ждали 10 сек